# EF Core performance loading large object graphs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This code from EF Framework 6, works in my existing project. It returns with the object within a minute at worse:

```
        return entityContext
            .StagingPatternSet
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternAccounts ) 
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternAddZeroess )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternAdditions )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities.Select( e => e.StagingPatternAddresses ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities.Select( e => e.StagingPatternAddresses.Select( a => a.StagingPatternAddressFields ) ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities.Select( e => e.StagingPatternMappings ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities.Select( e => e.StagingPatternNames ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities.Select( e => e.StagingPatternNames.Select( n => n.StagingPatternNameFields ) ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternBooleanFieldSelects )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternBooleanIntegers )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternCaseNumbers )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternConcatenates )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternConcatenates.Select( c => c.StagingPatternConcatenateFields ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternConstants )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternConstantValues )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternDateTimes )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts.Select( t => t.StagingPatternDelimitedTextFields ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts.Select( t => t.StagingPatternDelimitedTextSummaries ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts.Select( t => t.StagingPatternDelimitedTextSummaries.Select(s => s.StagingPatternDelimitedTextSummaryFields) ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternExcels )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternExtractNumbers )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternFleetStatements )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts.Select( f => f.StagingPatternFwTextFields ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts.Select( f => f.StagingPatternFwTextSummaries ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts.Select( f => f.StagingPatternFwTextSummaries.Select( s => s.StagingPatternFwTextSummaryFields ) ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternIbmDecimals )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternImpliedDecimals )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts.Select( l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLines ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts.Select( l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLines.Select( k => k.StagingPatternMultiRowTextKeys ) ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts.Select( l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLines.Select( f => f.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLineFields ) ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts.Select( l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSorts ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts.Select( l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSummaries ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts.Select( l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSummaries.Select( f => f.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSummaryFields ) ) )
        .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternNumberFormats )
        .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternNumerics )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternNumerics.Select( f => f.StagingPatternNumericFields ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternRedactSsns )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternReplaceSubstrings )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternSplitStrings )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternSsns )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternStrips )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternStripToNumericStrings )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternSubstrings )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternTranspositions )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternTranspositions.Select( v => v.StagingPatternTranspositionValues ) )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternVirtuals )
        .Include( sp => sp.StagingIoLiteUiManagements  )
            .Include( sp => sp.StagingPatternVirtuals.Select( f => f.StagingPatternVirtualFields ) )
            .Where( s => s.StagingPatternId == stagingPatternId ).ToFullyLoaded();
```

We're doing a re-write for this app in .NET Core. This code in EF Core 6, translates a little differently, but on any but the smallest queries, it may take 10 minutes when it returns an error temp db out of space. Enlarging the database temp db does not seem to yield results, and space is at a premium. We don't find this viable.

```
        var pattern = entityContext
            .StagingPatternSet
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingIoLiteUiManagements)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternAccounts)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternAddZeroess)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternAdditions)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities).ThenInclude(e => e.StagingPatternAddresses).ThenInclude(a => a.StagingPatternAddressFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities).ThenInclude(e => e.StagingPatternMappings)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternEntities).ThenInclude(e => e.StagingPatternNames).ThenInclude(n => n.StagingPatternNameFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternBooleanFieldSelects)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternBooleanIntegers)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternCaseNumbers)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternConcatenates)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternConcatenates).ThenInclude(c => c.StagingPatternConcatenateFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternConstants)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternConstantValues)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternDateTimes)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts).ThenInclude(t => t.StagingPatternDelimitedTextFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternDelimitedTexts).ThenInclude(t => t.StagingPatternDelimitedTextSummaries).ThenInclude(s => s.StagingPatternDelimitedTextSummaryFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternExcels)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternExtractNumbers)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternFleetStatements)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts).ThenInclude(f => f.StagingPatternFwTextFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternFwTexts).ThenInclude(f => f.StagingPatternFwTextSummaries).ThenInclude(s => s.StagingPatternFwTextSummaryFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternIbmDecimals)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternImpliedDecimals)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts).ThenInclude(l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLines).ThenInclude(k => k.StagingPatternMultiRowTextKeys)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts).ThenInclude(l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLines).ThenInclude(f => f.StagingPatternMultiRowTextLineFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts).ThenInclude(l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSorts)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternMultiRowTexts).ThenInclude(l => l.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSummaries).ThenInclude(f => f.StagingPatternMultiRowTextSummaryFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternNumberFormats)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternNumerics).ThenInclude(f => f.StagingPatternNumericFields)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternRedactSsns)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternReplaceSubstrings)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternSplitStrings)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternSsns)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternStrips)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternStripToNumericStrings)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternSubstrings)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternTranspositions).ThenInclude(v => v.StagingPatternTranspositionValues)
            .Include(sp => sp.StagingPatternVirtuals).ThenInclude(f => f.StagingPatternVirtualFields)
            .Where(s => s.StagingPatternId == stagingPatternId);

        var patternArray = await pattern.ToArrayAsync();
        return patternArray.ToList();
```

Any advise on handling this would be accepted. We often copy a pattern, make a small change, clear the object of ID values (0) and then save with a new name. So how do we load a 'fat' object such as this. All usable help welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can opt out of the "one-big-query" generated for multiple includes with either [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1), or by manually loading separate sub-graphs and letting the change tracker "fix up" all the relationships, or by using [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy), or [Explicitl Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit#explicit-loading) Navigation Properties as needed.

Comment: learning by microsoft (: +1 thanks